# DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [429]

Tags: api, flutter, dart, dio

i'm still learning create a News app using NewsAPI.org, and it was working, just at once gives me that error :

```
DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [429]
I/flutter (11270): #0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819:20)
I/flutter (11270): #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678:13)
I/flutter (11270): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (11270): #2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart)
I/flutter (11270): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (11270): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'data' was called on null.
I/flutter (11270): Receiver: null
I/flutter (11270): Tried calling: data
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 429 means, you sent too many requests. You can fix it by reducing requests or you can add some delay between requests. For this you can use Future delayed or Timer functions for this.

Comment: could you give me more explanation

Comment: How did you sent request? In a for loop or while loop? You cannot send so many requests in a short period. If you do that, server will block you and it returns HTTP 429. You can pass that like `Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => makeRequest());` or if you will send request continuously, you can use `Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 500), (Timer t) => makeRequest());`

Comment: i solve it .. i didn't set receiveTimeout , connectTimeout ... and ofc thank u a lot